# Are laying hens used as multiplication units?

Tags: agriculture, farm

In Diagram 1 of the following "https://www.ciwf.org.uk/media/5235024/The-life-of-laying-hens.pdf", it explains how laying hens are produced. Realistically I imagine it's more complex than this simple flow chart. Are multiplication units used to produce other multiplication units? Or, do the multiplication units solely come from breeding chickens and solely produce laying hen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about animal husbandry, not earth science.

Comment: Where should this be? You have an agriculture tag

Comment: The agriculture tag is for questions about how agriculture affects the Earth. It's not about farming or animal husbandry practices.